# URL not resolving in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, url

I am trying to open a url in IE that works fine in Firefox, but I get a Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage message.  The url works fine in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox... It is not a live url currently and is using local host file but other calls to the same domain are resolving so I don't suspect the host file to be the issue. Here is the url segement that is causing issues.

```
/v1/sso/facebook/init?body=%7B%22verb%22%3A%22GET%22%2C%22payload%22%3A%7B%22hash%22%3A%22genusSSOLinkPop%22%2C%22loc%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fdev.www.khou.com%2Fregister%3Fprofile%3D92da505591d%22%7D%2C%22callback%22%3A%7B%22success%22%3A%22bimreg.onloadlinksso%22%2C%22fail%22%3A%22bimreg.onfaillinksso%22%7D%2C%22auth%22%3A%7B%22token%22%3A%22d5de8efa8d8e66ce70f50781976ee033aac7e33e%22%2C%22nonce%22%3A%22f56e87594cbbd706ee9033cc049cba731f1b1ed5%22%2C%22session%22%3A%22MzU0ODMzN2U5ZjhhODQwMDAwNmUxOGVmZGUwZmY5NjMwN2VlNzhjNGMzOGE5NmVkZDQxMzk1YjM4MTk2NGVhMA%3D%3D%22%2C%22ts%22%3A%221296069789%22%2C%22sign%22%3A%22undefined%22%2C%22tp_sign%22%3A%22undefined%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22gwincr11%40yahoo.com%22%2C%22user%22%3A%221b87da2f9a993c2345353a14a3a01792afef51d5%22%7D%7D#easyXDM_genusSSOLinkPop_provider
```

Are there illegal characters I am not aware of?

Thanks,
Cory

Comment: IE8 has a 2000 character limit, this snippet is only 805, so that doesn't explain. If I prepend it with http://stackoverflow.com/ it works overhere: I get the server's 'page not found' page. So the request is being sent. Could you construct a  (bogus) URL to a real-world server that does not get sent?

Comment: I will see what I can do. thanks.

Comment: How is this url being used? xhr, iframe, or by easyXDM? I'm the author of the latter one so would like to rule this out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not showing the whole URL so it's hard to tell, but it might be related to this:

[Maximum URL length is 2,083 characters in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427)

another possibility is that you're using the `username@password:hostname` scheme, which has been disabled in (I think) IE8.

Comment: I am only at 843 characters, so that is not the issue... What is the username@password:hostname scheme?  I am not familiar with this restriction.

Comment: @Cory transmitting username and passwort in the URL doesn't work any more for security reasons. Are you using this?

Comment: Ah I see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489 no I am not doing this, it is a straight http call to something like www.stackoverflow.com so that does not seem be what they are defining here where the url is http(s)://username:password@server/resource.ext

Comment: @Cory ah, okay... No, I have no other ideas. We'd probably have to see a live link

Answer (score 0):

internet explorer has URL limitation of 2083 characters. Other browsers can handle over 64 000 characters. Could this be the reason?

Comment: wish it was, I am only at 843 characters.